# Having problems with iOS8 Core Location

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, core-location

Core Location usage change recently, but even after updating to the new specification I can't seem to get it working.

I tried starting a new project with just a view controller that changes its background color upon GPS coordinate finding or failure.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){

    CLLocationManager *locationManager;

}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    if (locationManager == nil)
    {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    }


    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark CLLocationManagerDelegate
//
//
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
{
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    NSLog(@"lat:%f lon:%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //Debug(@"did fail with error. stop updating and return error.");

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
}

@end
```

I added

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs your location to provide the best service.</string>
```

to the Info.plist file, and still... no changes, the location icon appears on the status bar near the battery but no location ever comes, real or simulated.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the change authorisation method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    // This method has to be here to trigger the UIAlertView
    switch (status) {
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
           break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined: {
            if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
                [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

*EDIT*

You're using the wrong delegate method. didUpdateToLocation has been deprecated. Use this instead:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it made no difference ;(

Comment: The location icon appearing suggests that the device is monitoring the location. Are you saying that the delegate callback never gets fired ?

Comment: No problem. Should have come up as a warning in the project but maybe not. :-) good luck